# convert to pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This is my SQL Select Statement which I'd like to convert to the one invoked within a PL/SQL code :

```
SELECT StockID 
  FROM StockPrice 
 WHERE StockType ='Technology' AND Price < 150 
    OR StockType ='Retail' AND Price < 150;
```

any ideas ...

Comment: and waht is wrong wth it in any sql language?

Comment: PL/SQL supports all Oracle SQL. What do you mean by convert it? What should the new procedure/function do exactly?

Answer (score 3):

A simple option, presuming that query returns a single value, is

```
DECLARE
  l_stockid stockprice.stockid%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT stockid
  INTO l_stockid
  FROM stockprice
  WHERE (stocktype = 'Technology' AND price < 150)
     OR (stocktype = 'Retail'     AND price < 150);
END;
/
```

Though, `WHERE` could be rewritten to

```
  WHERE price < 150
    AND stocktype in ('Technology', 'Retail')
```

If that `select` statement returns more than a single row, you'll get `too_many_rows` and the question is how do you want to handle it? Raise an exception? Select into a collection? Something different? It just depends.